# Multiple Instances working in azure cloud service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have **azure cloud service** with **2 instance** count **small vm** so any one could explain how it internally use instances?

Both instance running parallel or run second instance when first one would go down.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both running in parallel. You should read about it on the Azure Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me

edit: Cloud Services includes the load balancer in front of your web role instances automatically for external endpoints.

Comment: I have web role with instance count 2 that means request comes to web role divided into both instances through some algorithm. am I right?

Comment: can we override traffic distribution algo? like RoundRobin

Comment: i suggest you mark this answer as an answer and start a new question, or better read the docs, you questions are really basic. and no, you cannot alter those rules

Answer (score 1):

Both are running in parallel and each cloud service has one URL with a load balancer and it forwards the traffic to both instances.